# Purple boot screen with diagonal broken lines after selecting Windows 10 from dual boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I'm running Ubuntu and Windows 10 as a dual boot. When I select "Windows 10"  from GRUB menu, it gets stuck at purple boot screen with diagonal broken lines, and won't boot further,reference.
I worked without these problems since from many days, but I got this problem recently

[image]

Comment: Your Windows is not booting because your Windows has a problem. Your Windows problem is unrelated to the other OSes. You need to fix your Windows but that is off topic here.

Comment: Can you boot Ubuntu successfully? If yes, could you please run `sudo update-grub` and try to boot Windows again? If that still doesn't work, could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: @David Foerster   To run Boot-Info, again should I need to reinstall Ubuntu iso

Comment: I don't understand. You can install and run Boot-Info from your current Ubuntu installation or a live system as described in the article linked in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem while booting the system in safe mode and finally got the solution for my own problem.

Boot into Ubuntu, there follow the steps which are described in [this video](https://youtu.be/sueumjgGFkA) and which are also listed below.

1. Open the terminal and run this command: `sudo fdisk -l`
2. If a Windows partition exists, then update grub with this command: `sudo update-grub`
3. Restart your system with this command `sudo reboot` Then after loading you will be asked to select a boot option.

   Warning: This might not work on your PC. I have UEFI System for Windows 10. I installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode too.
4. After rebooting, select Windows 10 from grub menu, it may boot into safe mode. Then go to *System Configuration* -> *Boot* tab -> uncheck *Safe boot* -> Click *Apply* and then *OK*. Restart the system again.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydCsV.png]

```
Change the option in System Configuration to:
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have just to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, I have got this problem too, which was solved just by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key worked, but the problem persisted for me.

Repairing startup surprisingly fixed the issue for once.
Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when restarting -> Troubleshooting -> repair startup

Alternative fix, boot into advanced recovery mode, tap F8 or boot from recovery media. -> Troubleshooting -> cmd.
This is a last resort, you may want to check for any corruption first. And try less risky fixes like `sfc` and `dism` commands. Check out Windows Central's breakdown of each tool for more details on how to run those repairs in Advanced recovery mode.

```
bootrec /FixMbr 
bootrec /FixBoot 
bootrec /ScanOs 
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```